# How to write parquet file in partition in java similar to pyspark?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, parquet

I can write parquet file into partition in pyspark like this:

```
rdd.write
 .partitionBy("created_year", "created_month")
 .parquet("hdfs:///my_file")
```

The parquet file is auto partition into created_year, created_month. How to do the same in java? I don't see an option in ParquetWriter class. Is there another class that can do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your RDD into DataFrame and then call write parquet function.

```
df = sql_context.createDataFrame(rdd)
df.write.parquet("hdfs:///my_file", partitionBy=["created_year", "created_month"])
```