# How to output multiple s3 files in Parquet

Tags: hadoop, parquet

Writing parquet data can be done with something like the following. But if I'm trying to write to more than just one file and moreover wanting to output to multiple s3 files so that reading a single column does not read all s3 data how can this be done?

```
    AvroParquetWriter<GenericRecord> writer =
            new AvroParquetWriter<GenericRecord>(file, schema);

    GenericData.Record record = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema)
                .set("name", "myname")
                .set("favorite_number", i)
                .set("favorite_color", "mystring").build();
    writer.write(record);
```

For example what if I want to partition by a column value so that all the data with favorite_color of red goes in one file and those with blue in another file to minimize the cost of certain queries. There should be something similar in a Hadoop context. All I can find are things that mention [Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234731/how-to-write-parquet-file-in-partition-in-java-similar-to-pyspark) using something like

```
df.write.parquet("hdfs:///my_file", partitionBy=["created_year", "created_month"])
```

But I can find no equivalent to partitionBy in plain Java with Hadoop.

Comment: As far as I know, hadoop's implementation of NativeS3FileSystem does not support seek (partial content reads) on S3files. It downloads the whole file first.

Comment: You might however want to take a look at this: http://blog.cask.co/2015/10/multiple-outputs-in-cdap/

On there they state "With the newly built capabilities in CDAP users can now use MapReduce programs in CDAP to write to multiple outputs whether the output is a Parquet file in S3 or a Table dataset. "

Comment: I would write the code to do it but I haven´t worked with s3, just with the HDFS system in cloudera or horton distros. do you know what differences there are between them?

Answer (score 1):

In a typical Map-Reduce application, the number of output files will be the same as the number of reduces in your job. So if you want multiple output files, set the number of reduces accordingly:

`job.setNumReduceTasks(N);`

or alternatively via the system property:

`-Dmapreduce.job.reduces=N`

I don't think it is possible to have one column per file with the Parquet format. The internal structure of Parquet files is initially split by row groups, and only these row groups are then split by columns.

[image: Parquet format]